# removing switch calling function based on object type using polymorphism

Tags: c#, reflection, refactoring

I have a piece of code (shown below) where i want to be able to call a function depending on the object type that is passed in, i currently have a switch statement which manages this but it feels kinda dirty to me. What would the best method of refactoring the code to make use of polymorphism to enable me to remove the switch statement?

```
if (entity != null)    
{
    //Switch based on entity type
    switch (entity.GetType().Name)
    {

        case "Person":

            //Person implementation

            break;
        case "Organisation":
            //Organisation implementation


            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

**Edit:** For clarification of anyone else finding this, i dont have access to the Entity models source, which led me to mark answer as such, if it wasnt for this then i would have marked Jon's answer as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three approaches to eliminate the `switch`-based dispatch here:

- Give `Person` and `Organization` a common interface or superclass, and provide implementations based on the class,
- Implement [*Visitor Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) in the superclass / superinterface of `Person` and `Organization`, or
- Use `dynamic` dispatch.

The third approach works when you do not have access to source code of `Person` and `Organization`. An implementation would look like this:

```
// Add these methods to your class
private void ProcessEntity(Person p) {
    ...
}
// Each overload is specific for one subclass
private void ProcessEntity(Organization o) {
    ...
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
ProcessEntity((dynamic)entity);
```

C# will figure out which of the overloads to choose based on the runtime type of `entity`.

Answer (score 2):

To use polymorphism, you'd introduce an abstract method in whatever the base class is for all your entities:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public abstract void GiveMeABetterName();
}
```

(We don't know what you're trying to do, hence the name...

You'd then implement the method in each of your subclasses (`Person`, `Organization` etc). You can then just use:

```
entity.GiveMeABetterName();
```

where you currently have your `switch` block.

Now that isn't *always* an appropriate option - for example, what you're trying to do may be something outside the domain of your entity (e.g. displaying information in a GUI). If the code for each of those types *really* doesn't belong in your entities, you could:

- Use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which would work particularly well if there are multiple operations for each entity
- Have a `Dictionary<Type, Action>` or something similar to look up the action to take for each type
- Keep your existing approach, but use `is` or `as` instead of `switch` to avoid putting the names as string literals

Answer (score 1):

You can start by defining an interface which will define a contract for your entities.

```
public interface ISomething
{
    void YourMethod();
}
```

After that you can implement your entities `Person` and `Organization` and impelment `YourMethod` which will incorporate the functionality you need.

```
public class Person : ISomething
{
    public void YourMethod()
    {

    }
}

public class Organization: ISomething
{
    public void YourMethod()
    {

    }  

}
```

Finally, you will pass a reference to `ISomething` wherever you need

```
public void Method(ISomething smth)
        {
            smth.YourMethod();
        }
```

You can call this method in your code like this:

```
var person = new Person();
var org = new Organization();


Method(person); // will call implementation of person
Method(org) //will call implementation of organization
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
if (entity != null)
{
    if (entity is Person)
    {
        //Person implementation
    }
    else if (entity is Organisation)
    {
        //Organisation implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case you should create an interface or an abstract class from which each of your selected types should inherit or implement.

```
public interface Aggregator{
    void TestFunction();
}
```

or

```
public abstract class Aggregator{
   public abstract void TestFunction();
}
```

then each possible type of your entity should have

```
public class TypeOfYourEntity : Aggregator{
   //implementation of TestFunction
}
```

then in your function when you call `entity.TestFunction()` you are sure that the right implementation will be called